# Adding 2 objects to a List

Tags: c#

I am comparing Objects to see if they are equal, or have any differences.

If they are different, I want to store them together somehow, but I'm not sure how.  There will be multiple Objects of the same type to be added.

Is something like:

`List<T,T>` possible?

So if I compare Object A with Object B, and they are not the same, I could call:

```
List.Add(A,B).
```

So I would know that each object at each element were related?

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Create a class with two properties or use a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` or `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>`.

Comment: @Tim - huge respect to you, but if you're going to answer a question can you answer it rather than comment - otherwise those of us who do take the time to do so get accused of [copying the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527639/adding-2-objects-to-a-list/27527696?noredirect=1#comment43483949_27527696). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either create a class with two properties or use [`Tuple<T1,T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The former would look like

```
list.Add( new MyObject(A,B) )
```

The latter would then look like

```
list.Add( Tuple.Create(A,B) );
```

In order to initialise this list one would need to know the types of `A` and `B` - but lets assume `A` is of type `Foo` and `B` is of type `Bar` the list would be initialised as

```
var list = new List<Tuple<Foo,Bar>>()
```

Comment: Example of how to create an Empty Tuple, as this will be an expanding list as I loop through all the Objects.  I will keep adding them if they are different

Comment: @BhargavModi - no, copied from about 15 years of writing .NET code. \*rolleyes\*

Comment: How do you iniatilse the list in the latter example using the Tuple?  var list = new List<??>

Comment: @user3437721: you should get familiar with [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If you want a list full of strings use `new List<string>()` if you want one for your custom class `Foo` use `new List<Foo>()` and with tuples `new List<Tuple<string, string>>()`(presuming the type of both is string).

Answer (score 1):

> There will be multiple Objects of the same type to be added.

Then it sounds like you want a `List<List<T>>` (basically a jagged array). If there is some "key" value (e.g. a property that you are comparing) that can be used to identify the groups of "equal" objects then a `Dictionary<TKey,List<TValue>>` might offer some performance improvements.

Note that if you already *have* a collection you can use the `GroupBy` Linq method to group "equal" objects together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tuple to store objects of different type

```
Tuple<type1,type2>
```